# With what shortcut can I close the error message pop-up?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With what shortcut can I close the error pop-up dialog in Visual Studio code? (I use Ubuntu 17)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the shortcut list `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

From the menu, you will see a shortcut for `Close Notification messages`

Mostly it would be `Escape` button on your keyboard.